# Custom ListView is not displayed

Tags: java, android, android-listview

Following some tutorials, I managed to make a custom list.

But the whole screen is just a list

And now want to put the list below the form. And to make the whole screen make scroll along with the list (see the last item in the list, the form needs to rise)

The log (Toasty) says that the item was added, but nothing appears. I do not know if the problem is in how I add, or is the way I try to display

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/cliente" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/venda_form_cliente"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:hint="@string/selecione_um_cliente" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/produto" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/venda_form_prod"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:hint="@string/selecione_um_produto" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/quantidade" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/venda_form_qtd"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                    android:text="@string/um" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/valor" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/venda_form_valor"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:cursorVisible="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:inputType="none" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/desconto" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/venda_form_desc"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                    android:text="@string/zero" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/subtotal" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/venda_form_subtotal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:cursorVisible="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:inputType="none" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/venda_form_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/adicionar" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@android:id/list"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scrollbars="none" >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And my activity

```
public class VendaFormActivity extends Activity {

    private Cliente cliente;
//  private Spinner condicaoSelect;
    private Produto produto;
    private TextWatcher somar;
    private ItemVenda itemVenda;
    private ListaAdapter listaAdapter;
    private EditText inputQuantidade;
    private EditText inputDesconto;
    private EditText inputSubTotal;
    private EditText inputProduto;
    private EditText inputValor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_venda_form);

        inputProduto = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.venda_form_prod));
        inputValor = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.venda_form_valor));

        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.venda_form_cliente)).setOnClickListener(new ClickListener(this, ClienteActivity.class, MainActivity.REQUEST_CLIENTE));
        inputProduto.setOnClickListener(new ClickListener(this, ProdutoActivity.class, MainActivity.REQUEST_PRODUTO));

        //condicaoSelect = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.venda_form_condicao);
        //new CondicaoHelper(this).popular(condicaoSelect);

        bindCamposValores();
        fazerLista();
        bindBtnAdd();
    }

    private void limparCamposValores() {
        inputDesconto.setText("0.00");
        inputQuantidade.setText("1");
        inputSubTotal.getText().clear();
        inputProduto.getText().clear();
    }

    private void bindBtnAdd() {
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.venda_form_btn)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    Double quantidade = Double.parseDouble( inputQuantidade.getText().toString() );
                    Double desconto = Double.parseDouble( inputDesconto.getText().toString() );

                    itemVenda = new ItemVenda();
                    itemVenda.setDesconto(desconto);
                    itemVenda.setProduto(produto);
                    itemVenda.setQuantidade(quantidade);

                    listaAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
                    listaAdapter.getItens().add(itemVenda);
                    listaAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Foi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    limparCamposValores();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Invalido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // NPE no produto
                    // NumberFormat nos valores
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void fazerLista() {
        listaAdapter = new ListaAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        ((ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list)).setAdapter(listaAdapter);
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView descricao;
        protected TextView codigo;
        protected TextView ean;
        protected TextView referencia;
        protected TextView quantidade;
        protected TextView valor_unit;
        protected TextView valor_item;
    }

    private class ListaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ItemVenda>{
        private final Context context;
        private final List<ItemVenda> itens;

        public ListaAdapter(Context context) {
            super(context, R.layout.produto_list);
            this.context = context;
            this.itens = new LinkedList<ItemVenda>();
        }
        public ListaAdapter(Context context, List<ItemVenda> itens) {
            super(context, R.layout.produto_list, itens);
            this.context = context;
            this.itens = itens;
        }

        public List<ItemVenda> getItens() {
            return itens;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = null;
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.produto_list_item, null);

                final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.descricao = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.descricao);
                viewHolder.codigo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.codigo);
                viewHolder.ean = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ean);
                viewHolder.referencia = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.referencia);
                viewHolder.quantidade = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.quantidade);
                viewHolder.valor_unit = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.valor_unit);
                viewHolder.valor_item = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.valor_item);

                view.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                  view = convertView;
            }

            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

            ItemVenda item = itens.get(position);
            holder.descricao.setText(item.getProduto().getNome());
            holder.codigo.setText(item.getProduto().getCodigo());
            holder.ean.setText(item.getProduto().getEan());
            holder.referencia.setText(item.getProduto().getReferencia());
            holder.quantidade.setText(item.getQuantidade().toString());
            holder.valor_unit.setText(item.getProduto().getPreco().toString());
            holder.valor_item.setText(item.getSubTotal().toString());

            return view;
        }

    }

    private void bindCamposValores() {
        inputQuantidade = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.venda_form_qtd));
        inputDesconto = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.venda_form_desc));
        inputSubTotal = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.venda_form_subtotal));

        somar = new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) { }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) { }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                Double sub = 0.0;

                try{
                    itemVenda = new ItemVenda();
                    itemVenda.setQuantidade(Double.parseDouble(inputQuantidade.getText().toString()));
                    itemVenda.setDesconto(Double.parseDouble(inputDesconto.getText().toString()));
                    itemVenda.setProduto(produto);

                    sub = itemVenda.getSubTotal();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // algum campo não é numero/está vazio
                }

                inputSubTotal.setText(""+sub);
            }
        };

        // Se mudar o valor
        inputQuantidade.addTextChangedListener(somar);
        inputDesconto.addTextChangedListener(somar);

        // quando sair do campo
        inputQuantidade.setOnFocusChangeListener(new Focus("1"));
        inputDesconto.setOnFocusChangeListener(new Focus("0.00"));
    }

    private class Focus implements OnFocusChangeListener {

        private final String padrao;

        public Focus(String padrao){
            this.padrao = padrao;
        }

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(!hasFocus){

                Editable text = ((EditText) v).getText();
                if(null == text || "".equals(text.toString())){
                    text.append(padrao);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_venda_form, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_copiar:
                copiar();
                return true;

            case R.id.menu_simulacao:
                simulacao();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void copiar() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Nada ainda", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    private void simulacao() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SimulacaoPagtoActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, MainActivity.REQUEST_SIMULACAO);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == MainActivity.REQUEST_CLIENTE) {

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                cliente = (Cliente) intent.getSerializableExtra(MainActivity.RESULT_MODEL_LIST);
                ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.venda_form_cliente)).setText(cliente.getNome());
            }

        } else if (requestCode == MainActivity.REQUEST_PRODUTO) {

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                produto = (Produto) intent.getSerializableExtra(MainActivity.RESULT_MODEL_LIST);
                inputProduto.setText(produto.getNome());
                inputValor.setText(""+produto.getPreco());
                somar.afterTextChanged(null);
            }

        } else if(requestCode == MainActivity.REQUEST_SIMULACAO){
            // o que fazer quando voltar da simulação ?
        }
    }

}
```

Finally, my item layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descricao"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#333"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/codigo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="CODIGO" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ean"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="EAN" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/referencia"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="REFERENCIA" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quantidade"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="QUANT." />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/valor_unit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="VLR UNIT" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/valor_item"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="VLR ITEM" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**UPDATE**

When I add an item in the list, nothing is shown. But after I click a TextEdit, and the virtual keyboard up, after typing some value, I close the keyboard, then the adapter.getView () is called and the list appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found the solution**

**1)** The adapter have 2 constructors, but just 1 with `List<ItemVenda> itens`, and it isn't called.
I fixed it.

**2)** To add an item on the list, I need to call `adapter.add()` and not adapter.getItens().add()`. I think this trigger others methods.

**3)** Finally, to take the scroll list, and apply the scroll across the screen, I need to increase the size of the list. Then I override the method adapter.add(), and calculate the new height of the list, and add `android:scrollbars="none"` on `ListView`

Thanks to all, especially to `@Marek`

Answer (score 4):

I think I found your problem. Shouldn't the following code:

```
((ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list)).setAdapter(listaAdapter);
```

Be:

```
((ListView) findViewById(R.id.list)).setAdapter(listaAdapter);
```

instead?

You are trying to find a default Android view, rather than the view that you have created, which means that you are not actually setting the adapter for your `ListView`.

Comment: I confess that I do not have much experience with Android, but I was surprised to find that this part is correct

Comment: @Falci so...did this fix the problem?

Comment: No problem. I had a similar issue a while back. Glad to help.

Comment: @Falci If this answer helped you, please tick the box next to it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about that, but if you want the list to be scrollable with the activity, you should use ScrollView, and then check if you scroll the list or the view itself. Try it

You can also try to see with debugger if the item was actually added to the list. I hope you will find an error.

Comment: ListView inside ScrollView cause `UnsupportedOperationException`. Another thing, adapter.getView () is never called

Comment: Maybe you will be able to help me in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661647/drawingpanel-canvas-not-drawing-in-a-android-fragment-from-tutorial Thanks a lot!